# Hermitian Adjoint of differential operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum

I came across this equation (identity) (Eq. 4 in this [paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/jp073213k)):

> $\int(-i d\psi/dx)^*\psi dx = \int \psi^*(-i d\psi/dx) dx + id(\psi^*\psi)/dx\mid_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$

I have trouble proving it. I tried to use integration by parts but could not reach there. How do we take complex conjugate (Hermitian Adjoint) of the differential operator that occurs in this equation and also of any general function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that
\begin{align}
  i\frac{d(\psi^*\psi)}{dx} 
&=\frac{d\big[(-i\psi)^*\psi\big]}{dx} \\
&= \frac{d(-i\psi)^*}{dx}\psi + (-i\psi)^*\frac{d\psi}{dx} \\
&= \left(-i\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)^*\psi + \psi^*\left(i\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right) \\
\end{align}
Now subtract the second term on the right from both sides to get
\begin{align}
  \psi^*\left(-i\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)+i\frac{d(\psi^*\psi)}{dx} 
&= \left(-i\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)^*\psi
\end{align}
and finally integrate both sides from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ to obtain (as Stan Liou pointed out in the comments)
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty\psi^*\left(-i\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)+i\psi^*\psi\Big|_{-\infty}^\infty 
 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(-i\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)^*\psi
$$
Notice that the boundary term you wrote in the identity has an erroneous derivative that goes away when you actually evaluate the integral and use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: You're right, except for that it's not the desired identity, because the desired identity is just plain false. I suspect a typo in the article.

Comment: @StanLiou Hmm really?  Is there a sign missing perhaps?  I can't see where there's an error.

Comment: When you integrate, you get an $i(\psi^*\psi)\mid_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ term, rather than $id(\psi^*\psi)/dx\mid_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ as the OP has.

Comment: Oh of course.  Thanks for pointing that out!  I somehow kept seeing the correct boundary term even though i was staring at it for a few minutes.  Thanks Stan.

Comment: It does not seem to be a typo in the paper since the author explicitly mentions about the derivative of the density ($\psi^*\psi$) in the line following the equation. Starting with LHS (rather than the *reverse* way) how do we get RHS?

Comment: @DurgaDatta Seems like an error to me.  Even on dimensional grounds, the boundary term does not make sense with a derivative in it.

Comment: @DurgaDatta The identity is just wrong and easy to correct. The author doesn't actually reference the incorrect version in any of the following at all--he says that "the product $\psi^*\psi = \rho$" vanishes on the boundary at infinity, which is what's actually needed for hermiticity. He says that *in addition to that*, the derivatives vanish, which may have given you that impression. The next statement regarding a nonvanishing remainder in 3D is ambiguous regarding which version of the identity he has in mind. So he doesn't explicitly use $id(\psi^*\psi)/dx\mid_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ anywhere.

Comment: Exact quote: "The product $\psi^*\psi = \rho$, and the density together with it derivatives, vanish on the boundaries at infinity, but not when the boundary has a finite value. ..." Which seems poorly phrased, but that he's claiming that $\rho^*\rho$ is among the things that vanish on the boundary at infinity is clear. So his subsequent inferences follow from the corrected version just as well.

Comment: Is there a alternative way prove the equation (corrected) by starting with the LHS. I want to know how one would think when on sees the LHS (for the first time) and want to mentally compare that with its equivalent RHS form.

Comment: @DurgaDatta Once the extra derivative is removed (since it's inconsistent for dimensional reasons as Josh said), the formula is just a particular case of integration by parts with some $i$'s sprinkled in, whose conjugates change some signs. So you can prove it by IbP formula without moving any terms across sides. But IbP is itself just a re-arrangment of the integral of the Leibniz rule for differentiation, so really you'd be doing the same thing as this answer anyway.